# How to set CLASSPATH for Apache Derby DB

Tags: classpath, derby

I tried to set the Path environment variable of entering the path: "C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jdk1.8.0_101 \ db \ lib" (.jar file path) but nothing ...
I created a new variable called CLASSPATH by entering the same path and still nothing ...
How can I link this path to the compiler?

[compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gT71y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set CLASSPATH to the **directory** where the jar files are stored; you have to specify the actual jar file by its full name.

This is a difference between a directory full of java .class files, versus a directory full of java .jar files.

So set your CLASSPATH to:

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\db\lib\derby.jar;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\db\lib\derbyclient.jar
```

In your particular case, since the only class you're trying to reference is `ClientDriver`, which is in `derbyclient.jar`, you could just set CLASSPATH to `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\db\lib\derbyclient.jar` and leave `derby.jar` out, but at some point in the future you might want to reference other Derby classes, such as `EmbeddedDriver`, so you might as well put both `derby.jar` and `derbyclient.jar` into your CLASSPATH now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! you were very exhaustive! =)